# Problema na inicialização do Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Acabei de baixar o Eclipse (pois vou mexer com desenvolvimento Android), mas ao tentar abrir aparece a mensagem abaixo.

O JRE está instalado na minha máquina, pois consigo usar o NetBeans normalmente, sem problemas.

Detalhe é que quando digite "java -version" no cmd, fala que o comando "java" não existe.

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations:
>   D:\Downloads\eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
>   javaw.exe in your current PATH

Comment: Já experimentou acrescentar o caminho do java no path?

Comment: Bacco, pra isso eu preciso alterar a variável de ambiente "path", incluindo o caminho da pasta bin do JRE e incluir uma variável JAVA_HOME com o caminho da pasta do Java. É isso mesmo?

Comment: pasta bin do **JDK**, de resto voce acertou tudo

Comment: Fiz isso, mas agora apresenta esta mensagem: 
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll".

Answer (score 3):

Segundo [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk) reposta do SO, você não está usando **versões compatíveis**.

Você precisa ter o conjunto:

- 64-bit OS (Sistema Operacional)
- 64-bit Java
- 64-bit Eclipse

Ou:

- 32-bit OS (Sistema Operacional)
- 32-bit Java
- 32-bit Eclipse

Caso esse não for o seu problema, tente adicionar ao arquivo *eclipse.ini* o seguinte (64 bit):

> -vm C:\path-to-64bit-java\bin\javaw.exe
>
> **Exemplo:** -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\javaw.exe

Qualquer dúvida pergunte nos comentários, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Deyel, fiz da forma que você pediu, não deu certo, fiz de outra forma também (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll) mas não deu certo :(

Comment: Percebi uma coisa, como seu Windows possui Program Files (x86) significa que ele é 64 bit, mas vejo que seu JDK está instalado na pasta x86 que é 32 bit. Estou errado?

Comment: @user7618, você precisa baixar o Java correto de acordo com o seu sistema operacional. Após isso, vai precisar mudar o caminho do mesmo na variável de sistema PATH. Essa resposta está correta, é só manter tudo instalado para a arquitetura correta do SO.

Answer (score 0):

Eu instalei o Java 11 e o Eclipse e tudo estava funcionando muito bem, mas aí resolvi baixar no `Eclipse MarketPlace` um tema escuro pra poder visualizar melhor o código. Todavia, no outro dia fui iniciar o Eclipse e apareceu essa mesma mensagem de erro.

Eu então eu fui em painel de controle, avançado, "variáveis do ambiente do sistema" e inclui no item "path" o seguinte caminho:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\javaw.exe
```

Reiniciei e consegui abri o Eclipse com sucesso.